# sort of the flow order

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

return test.ToList();

sort of the flow order

Comment: Have you tried the LinQ function `.OrderBy(x=>x.Name)` ?

Comment: Check out the MS Linq 101 site: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b Got some nice simple examples for all the basic LINQ methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx)

```
return _Repository.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name)
                           .OrderBy(r => r)
                           .Distinct()
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: If you are already selecting just the name you want to order by `r => r`.

Answer (score 1):

[**MSDN Order by Example**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Do order by like this

```
_Repository.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name).OrderBy(y => y).Distinct().ToList();
```

or

```
_Repository.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().OrderBy(y => y).ToList();
```

or

```
var names = 
        (from u in _Repository.GetAll()
        order by u.Name 
        select u.Name).Distinct();
```

Image represention of ordering data

Read full post : [SQL to LINQ ( Visual Representation )](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2010/12/sql-to-linq-visual-representation.html)

[image]

Comment: If you are already selecting the name (as in first 2 examples) you want to order by `y => y`